# Instagram oEmbed API Invalid parameter

Tags: facebook, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, oembed

I have a Facebook app with advances access to oEmbed Reads permission.
For more than a year now, I've been using the Instagram oEmbed endpoint on Instagram accounts with no issues.

Since a month ago, I started getting Invalid parameter error with response of the sort:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid parameter",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 2207047,
        "is_transient": false,
        "error_user_title": "Invalid URL",
        "error_user_msg": "The request parameter 'url' is malformed or does not refer to an embeddable media.",
        "fbtrace_id": "xxxxxxx"
    }
}
```

When sending requests to
`https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/instagram_oembed&url=https://instagram.com/{username}&access_token=xxxxxx`

The [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/instagram-oembed/) now refers to Instagram posts, which is confusing to me.

Alternatively, using the oembed_page endpoint as per the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/oembed-page/)
Returns a similar error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Invalid parameter",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": xxxxx"
  }
}
```

Is anyone else having this same issue?
Is the oEmbed endpoint specific to posts?
How to go about retrieving an Instagram account/page info?

Thanks

Comment: _"The docs now refers to Instagram posts, which is confusing to me."_ - that in turn confuses me, in the opposite direction - because I don't think this was ever _meant_ to embed full user profiles anywhere to begin with. _"Is the oEmbed endpoint specific to posts?"_ - I am pretty sure it is, yes. _"How to go about embedding an Instagram account/page?"_ - I don't think they provide anything for that.

Comment: _"Alternatively, using the oembed_page endpoint as per the docs Returns a similar error"_ - that one is explicitly for _Facebook_ pages, but not IG accounts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used it to get account level info; profile picture url, among other details.

Answer (score 0):

You've made two mistakes on the query part:

- first `&` should be a `?`
- url isn't correctly encoded

It should be:

> graph.facebook.com/v16.0/instagram_oembed?url=https%3A%2F%2Finstagram.com%2F{username}&access_token=xxxxxx

Note that the username, if it contains special characters, should be escaped too.